# Color a un document.write

Tags: javascript, html

quisiera saber que forma hay de que el texto dentro de un document.write, aparezca en un color determinado, por ejemplo amarillo. todo esto desde un .js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
document.write("amarillo")
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Usando `document.write`

Aunque hay maneras más eficientes como usar `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML` (o con ID) para referirse a una zona específica del documento, usando `document.write` podrías hacerlo de esta forma:

```
document.write('<p style="color:yellow">amarillo</p>');
```

Añadiendo la etiqueta `p` contenida con estilo de css, en este caso color: Yellow

## Usando `getElement`

Aunque no soy experto ni mucho menos, la forma que yo utilizo para escribir en una zona *específica* del documento es la siguiente:

```js
document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML = "Contenido!!"
```

```css
#myContent{
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="myContent"></div>
```

Haciendo referencia a un `<div>` especifico (en este caso `myContent`) en tu html para no modificar todo.

Usando `innerHTML` puedes incrustar en tu documento HTML similar al que quieres con `document.write`.

### (EDIT) Concatenar varios `getElement`

Para concatenar varios de ellos puedes hacerlo usando:

```js
document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML += "Contenido 1";
document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML += "Contenido 2";
document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML += "Contenido 3";

document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML += `
<p>También puedo añadir contenido así</p>
<p>Y poner más...</p>`
```

```html
<div id="myContent"></div>
```

Usando `+=` te aseguras de no sobrescribir lo que ya había en el documento.

También es ideal si quieres añadir mucho código mediante javascript usar la comilla inversa (acento grave) ` para poder escribir código dentro sin tener que preocuparte en escapar las comillas dobles y simples.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me sirivió mucho

Comment: Acabo de modificar la respuesta para que sea aún más clara y ayudarte a mejorar. Si te sirvió dale a la ✅ !

Comment: ¿y si quiero hacer una concatenación, de que manera podía?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con una concatenación?

Comment: así: document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML += "más contenido!!!" o dicho de otra forma: document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML = document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML + "Contenido!!"

Comment: Te edito la respuesta a la pregunta y así te lo detallo con un snippet.